# mongodb 3.0.3 Ubuntu 14.04.2 AWS m3.medium Upstart PID mismatch

Tags: mongodb, ubuntu, upstart

Is it possible to run mongod via upstart and keep track of the PID via start-stop-daemon or otherwise?

After following these instructions on the mongodb docs page for ubuntu installation:

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv 7F0CEB10
echo "deb http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu "$(lsb_release -sc)"/mongodb-org/3.0 multiverse" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb-org-3.0.list
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y mongodb-org
```

All remnants of the ubuntu package have been removed prior to this.

I now have a running instance of mongod on boot, via Upstart. But for some reason Upstart and initctl do not know about it. It starts up fine, but initctl thinks it's in stop/waiting state.

To wit:

My /etc/mongod.conf.yml:

```
storage:
  dbPath: /var/lib/mongodb
  journal:
    enabled: true

systemLog:
  destination: file
  path: /var/log/mongodb/mongod.log
  logAppend: true
  logRotate: rename
  component:
    accessControl:
      verbosity: 2

net:
   bindIp: 127.0.0.1
   port: 27017

processManagement:
  fork: true

setParameter:
   enableLocalhostAuthBypass: false

security:
  authorization: disabled
```

My /etc/init/mongod.conf upstart script (renamed `mongodb.pid` to `mongod.pid`):

```
# Ubuntu upstart file at /etc/init/mongod.conf

# Recommended ulimit values for mongod or mongos
# See http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/ulimit/#recommended-settings
#
limit fsize unlimited unlimited
limit cpu unlimited unlimited
limit as unlimited unlimited
limit nofile 64000 64000
limit rss unlimited unlimited
limit nproc 32000 32000

kill timeout 300 # wait 300s between SIGTERM and SIGKILL.

pre-start script
  DAEMONUSER=${DAEMONUSER:-mongodb}
  if [ ! -d /var/lib/mongod ]; then
    mkdir -p /var/lib/mongodb && chown mongodb:mongodb /var/lib/mongodb
  fi
  if [ ! -d /var/log/mongod ]; then
    mkdir -p /var/log/mongodb && chown mongodb:mongodb /var/log/mongodb
  fi

  touch /var/run/mongod.pid

  chown $DAEMONUSER /var/run/mongod.pid;

  if test -f /sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage/enabled; then
    echo never > /sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage/enabled
  fi

  if test -f /sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage/defrag; then
    echo never > /sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage/defrag
  fi

end script

start on runlevel [2345]
stop on runlevel [06]

script
  ENABLE_MONGOD="yes"
  CONF=/etc/mongod.conf.yml
  DAEMON=/usr/bin/mongod
  DAEMONUSER=${DAEMONUSER:-mongodb}

  if [ -f /etc/default/mongod ]; then . /etc/default/mongod; fi

  # Handle NUMA access to CPUs (SERVER-3574)
  # This verifies the existence of numactl as well as testing that the command works
  NUMACTL_ARGS="--interleave=all"
  if which numactl >/dev/null 2>/dev/null && numactl $NUMACTL_ARGS ls / >/dev/null 2>/dev/null
  then
    NUMACTL="$(which numactl) -- $NUMACTL_ARGS"
    DAEMON_OPTS=${DAEMON_OPTS:-"--config $CONF"}
  else
    NUMACTL=""
    DAEMON_OPTS="-- "${DAEMON_OPTS:-"--config $CONF"}
  fi

  if [ "x$ENABLE_MONGOD" = "xyes" ]
  then
    exec start-stop-daemon --start \
        --chuid $DAEMONUSER \
        --pidfile /var/run/mongod.pid \
        --make-pidfile \
        --exec $NUMACTL $DAEMON $DAEMON_OPTS
  fi
end script
```

After a reboot I see this:

```
$ ps aux | grep mongo
mongodb   1085  0.2  1.1 363764 46704 ?        Sl   11:57   0:06 /usr/bin/mongod --config /etc/mongod.conf.yml
```

And everything appears to be fine. But the mongod.pid file does not store the same pid as the process:

```
$ cat /var/run/mongod.pid
985
```

Should be 1085.

What is the best way to fix this so Upstart has access to the actual PID?

**UPDATE:** tried to add `expect daemon` and `expect fork` with some change in behavior: initctl now sees a PID and denotes that mongod is running, but has the wrong PID. This means any subsequent command like `sudo stop mongod` or `sudo start mongod` will hang. Neither fork or daemon seems to fix this; what am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Ok so a bit of egg on my face - I was overlooking the fact that my shiny new `/etc/mongod.conf.yml` contained `processManagement.fork: true`. Setting this to false allows `start-stop-daemon` to capture the appropriate PID.